# Variable to store data, that can be accessed by any class

Tags: java, class, public

I have created a class called `aptSchedule` which, like its name suggests, keeps track of appointments in the form of a schedule. I would like to create a method that looks for and finds the first open appointment. In order to create this method I must first figure out a way to find all appointments. I figure that I will need to create a public variable of sorts, but I am not very familiar with Java and I was curious where and how should I create such a variable? Am I explaining myself well enough?

Thank you,
Evan

Comment: Are your appointments objects?

Comment: Note: Class names should start with a capital letter. (Like `AptSchedule`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to store all the appointments in some sort of collection, let's go with a simple `List<Appointment>` (assuming each appointment is stored in a(n objec of type) `Appointment`).  Then you can have your class like this:

```
public class aptScheduler
{
  List<Appointment> appts = new LinkedList<Appointment>();

  public aptScheduler()
  {
    // constructor
  }

  public Appointment findAppointment()
  {
    // search for appointment in appts, and return the first suitable one
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay, so I would have two classes then? First being called `Appointment` and the second being called `AptScheduler`?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're looking for a `Singleton`.

```
public class MySingleton {
  private static MySingleton _instance
  private MySingleton();
  public static getInstance() {
    if(_instance == null) { _instance = new MySingleton(); }
    return _instance;
  }

  // Add your scheduling methods here I guess
}
```

Bear in mind that while singletons do the job but they can add some pretty tight coupling to your code.

**Edit**: I may have misinterpreted your question incorrectly.  This is if you are looking to have your variable globally accessible.